# Split column in CSV based on a character

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to split a column in CSV to two columns based on `/` as the character. I know how to split a column but using a character I need help with.

So the column I want to split is:

Input: Column a = abc/124

Output: Column a = abc Column b = 124

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please share your efforts! You may want to take a look at the [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)...

Comment: @aschipfl I am actually looking for a way where within the for loop i can search for the character and then based on that separate the column and create 2 different columns

Comment: And store the output in the same file basically oevrwriting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=/" %%a in (inputfile.txt) do >>outputfile.txt echo %%a %%b
move /y outputfile.txt inputfile.txt
```

I'd suggest you leave the second line out and check to begin with, just in case the processing isn't what you want, the original file isn't overwritten.

You can replace the space between `%%a` and `%%b` with a comma if you prefer.